# LSZ Reduction Formula and Wavepackets in Peskin

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

In Section 7.2 of Peskin and Schroeder, the LSZ Reduction formula is discussed. I can follow the discussion leading up to the equation after (7.41) [at the bottom of Pg. 225]:
$$\sum_\lambda \int\frac{d^3K}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_\mathbf{K}}\left(\prod_{i=1,2}\int\frac{d^3k_i}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^4x_i\, e^{i\tilde{p_i}\cdot x_i}\varphi(\mathbf{k_i})\right)$$
$$\times\left<\Omega|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|\lambda_\mathbf{K}\right>\left<\lambda_\mathbf{K}|T\{\phi(x_3)\dots\}|\Omega\right>$$

where $|\lambda_\mathbf{K}\rangle$ is a state with momentum $\mathbf{K}$.

The authors then proceed on to say that:

> The state $|\lambda_\mathbf{K}\rangle$ is annihilated by two field operators constrained to lie in distant wavepackets. It must therefore consist of two distinct excitations of the vacuum at two distinct locations.

I am not able to follow the reasoning behind these two sentences. Ami I missing something very trivial? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should cite the book correctly, i.e. put `is` before annihilated. What is meant is that two annihilation operators act on $|\lambda_{\mathbf{K}}\rangle$. I guess that's part of how the authors justify the decomposition in the next step.

Comment: Sorry for the typo; I corrected it. I think I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot.